# Fat12 emulation

Tags: stm32, fat, fatfs

I implemented FatFS in internal memory of MCU STM32 [Chan's](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) library. Now I try to emulate bigger volume of flash device to receive large files from PC.
I can do it by changing two places of FatFS image:
1. By changing **MBR_start + 12** field value of **MBR** sector to required amount of sectors to emulate (address 0x1CA, LBA format):
[image]
2. By changing total number of sectors in the filesystem in FAT12 boot sector:
[image]

But the max number I can put there ix 0x13F (in LBA format) to emulate 142KB flash storage visible for PC. If I try to change that fields to higher I value my USB mass storage emulation fails and PC says me that USB device is not recognized.

Here is link for my FAT12 FS storage binary scan:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/GddY/6rvUuyPHx

Did someone do same things? 
I can't find any forum of FatFS gurus.
Thank you for any suggestion.